# On the balcony, what is she doing? - is this acceptable?

Tags: sentence-construction, usage, sentence-usage

**Example 1**

> What is she doing on the balcony?

**Example 2**

> On the balcony, what is she doing?

Are both of them acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

They are both acceptable, but in spoken English, and depending on emphasis, there are several ways of interpreting the two.

Example 1 could be pretty much as it sounds. You and I are both aware of a woman on a balcony, and you are simply asking me what she is doing while there. But if you placed the emphasis on "she" then the meaning of the word "doing" could change from referring to her actions to her mere presence. So perhaps we have the British Royal Family on the balcony of Buckingham Palace, including The Duchess Cornwall. A critic of might exclaim:

> Oh my word! Is that Camilla Parker Bowles? **What is *she* doing on the balcony!?**

On the other hand, perhaps Camilla being seen with the Royals is now accepted, but not on a place as symbolic as the Palace balcony:

> Oh that's a bit much. I mean, I guess Camilla is here to stay, but **what is she doing on the *balcony***?

In Example 2, there could be the suggestion that while you are aware of the woman on the balcony, I am not. So you first draw my attention to the fact that she is there, and *then* ask me what she is doing:

> Look! Over there! **On the balcony!** **What** on earth **is she *doing***!